# How to use preciseDiff from readable-range.js Plugin

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using Dynamic CRM 2013 and need to calculate date difference between 2 dates. I added to the form **moment.js** and **readable-range.js**.

All functions in moment.js are working fine. When it comes to  preciseDiff from readable-range.js and use:

```js
var bDt = new moment("2/22/2009");
var eDt = new moment("2/29/2016");
var dtDiff = moment.preciseDiff(bDt, eDt);
```

I am getting the following error:
**Object doesn't support property or method 'preciseDiff'**

Please advise.

Comment: is `preciseDiff()` part of moment API?

Comment: preciseDiff() is a function in readable-range.js whish is a moment.js plugin to display human-readable date/time ranges
http://codebox.org.uk/pages/moment-date-range-plugin

Comment: sounds like that plugin isn't included or path is wrong or order of include isn't right

Comment: The plugin is included and. It is immediately after moment.js and it is in the same path of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `new` operator with moment.

Also, if you are passing values in that format, you should provide a format string, otherwise values like `1/2/2014` might be interpreted as Jan 2nd in some regions, and Feb 1st in others.

Other than that, there's nothing wrong with your code.

```
var bDt = moment("2/22/2009", "M/DD/YYYY");
var eDt = moment("2/29/2016", "M/DD/YYYY");
var dtDiff = moment.preciseDiff(bDt, eDt);
```

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qa8r3e6j/)